# Run Php Script contuniously on Background

Tags: php, sockets, nohup

I have written server.php to accept connection from client through tcp socket.
and i have use

```
set_time_limit(0);
include_once("include/class.db.php");
while (true)
{
receive_message('x.x.x.x','8855',50);
}

function receive_message($ipServer,$portNumber,$nbSecondsIdle)
{
 // creating the socket...
 $socket = stream_socket_server('tcp://'.$ipServer.':'.$portNumber, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket)
{
echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
}
else
 {
// while there is connection, i'll receive it... if I didn't receive a message within $nbSecondsIdle seconds, the following function will stop.
while ($conn = @stream_socket_accept($socket,$nbSecondsIdle))
{
 $message= fread($conn, 1024);
 if($message!=''){
 echo 'I have received that : '.$message;
 // insert into database
 $sql = "insert into `data_log` (`id`,`message_text`) values (NULL,'$message')";
 $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $sql);
}
 fputs ($conn, "OK\n");
 fclose ($conn);
}
fclose($socket);
}
}
```

Then i run

```
nohup php server.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

to run the server in background. It all works fine. But the socket automatically closed after few hours or lets say the php script ends after few hours. As my need is to run the script in background until i manually stop it.
what may be the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: well - you could start troubleshooting with piping your program output in a logfile instead of /dev/null. and as a preliminary measure you can write a cronjob checking every now and then if your script is still running, and restarting it if not.

Comment: Probably after some time db connection was closed and script execution stopped, or you have run out of memory. Please check your connection at first.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann using file instead of /dev/null create a huge file about 20gb in just one day. so i use /dev/null

Comment: then eliminate all the unneccessary outputs so you're left with error messages.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i have pipe the output to logfile, now i'll come back with the log report after the script terminated.

Comment: @HardyRust i think you may right, the db connection may stopped after 8 hour idel and that makes the script terminated. But it will be clear after the output log.

Answer (score 2):

You should clearly understand, than php is not supposed to be used for such things. PHP-script runs, does some work and dies - thats its destiny. And any demon you create on php will die for some reason.

But it is very easy to create demons on php. So what should we do?

For demon scripts you should implement *supervisor*.

First, you have your script, just as you described above. Sometimes it is useful to implement some break-conditions for this script, such as process memory limit via [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)

Second, you implement supervisor script for your demon. What is that thing? Simply, some script, which you should call every 1 minute from cron. This script will:

1. Check if your demon script is still running. Currently running processes via shell can be used for this purpose
2. Run another instance if your demon has terminated.
3. Exit

The conception of supervisor is very useful. You can implement any business logic there, e.g. run exactly number of instances of demon. Its awesome for such sort of scripts like RabbitMQ consumers.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your script in loop with `sleep` time mentioned to sleep it for few seconds. For example:

```
while(1 < 2) {
    //your code
    sleep(1);
}
```

Then you can use `nohup` command as

```
nohup php yourscript.php &
```

So that it will run in background and to check if it's running. Use `top` command to see background porcess it will be running having command as php in top processes.